# react-virtualized, SystemJS and CDN

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I would like to use react-virtualized in a web application via cdnjs and SystemJS.

From all the examples that I have seen, it seems that react-virtualized and react libs are loaded locally, then bundled with Webpack before being included in a web page. Now I would like to use it via cdnjs without Webpack by simply importing it with SystemJS. But when I tried that I am getting errors saying that it can't find React.

I was wondering if anyone has tried this before, and whether this is supported at all by react-virtualized. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
For clarity, I have included some code to show what I am trying to do.

**index.html**:

```
...
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.0-alpha.1/system.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.config({
        map: {
            "react":"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js",
            "react-dom":"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js",
            "react-virtualized":"https://unpkg.com/react-virtualized/dist/umd/react-virtualized.js"
        }
  </script>
</head>
...
```

**main.jsx**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column} from 'react-virtualized';
...
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is possible using the UMD build of `react-virtualized`. You can see an example of that being done [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6syKo8cx3RfoO96hXFT1). In order for it to work though, you'll need to also import UMD builds of `react-with-addons` and `react-dom` since `react-virtualized` depends on them.

For example:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/dist/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-virtualized/dist/umd/react-virtualized.js"></script>
```

The `react-virtualized` UMD build expects React and ReactDOM to be loaded in the global space.

Alternately there should be a way with SystemJS to expose `react-dom` and `react-with-addons` as globals for libraries like `react-virtualized` to consume. I'm not a SystemJS user, but I think it might be something like this:

```
System.config({
  meta: {
    'path/to/react-virtualized.js': {
      globals: {
        React: 'path/to/react-addons-shallow-compare.js',
        ReactDOM: 'path/to/react-dom.js'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @brianvaughn. In your example you have loaded react libs as globals. Will the UMD builds still work if I use SystemJS to import them as modules?

Comment: The `react-virtualized` UMD build expects React and ReactDOM to be loaded in the global space. There may be another alternative that would be better. I'll edit my answer to mention it, b'c it would benefit from formatting and comments don't support that.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I had some time to look at this again. Thanks to @brianvaughn's suggestion, I have managed to resolve this with the following:

```
System.config({
   meta: {
      "react-virtualized": {
         exports: "ReactVirtualized",
         format: "global",
         globals: {
            React: "react",
            ReactDOM: "react-dom"
         }
      }
   },
   map: {
      "react":    "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js",
      "react-dom":"https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
      "react-virtualized":"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-virtualized/9.10.1/react-virtualized.min.js",
   }
})
```

### main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as ReactVirtualized from 'react-virtualized';

let Table = ReactVirtualized.Table;
let Column = ReactVirtualized.Column;
let AutoSizer = ReactVirtualized.AutoSizer;
...
```